# Do not want parent controller to run

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui.router

Here is the sample code :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: '/contacts',
        templateUrl: './home/contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    })
    .state('contacts.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: './home/list.html',
        controller: 'listController'

    })
    .state('contacts.list.accounts', {
        url: '/accounts',
        templateUrl: './home/account.html',
        controller: 'accountController'
    })
```

list.html have two ng-controller in the two divs.

so when i go to $state.go('contacts.list.account')

then my contact.html controllers run if i have on page then my list two ng-controllers run and then my actual controller run .

I don't want contact and list controllers to run .

Is there any way in which my child states do not run the parent states controller plz help

Comment: Yes, don't make them child states. Just change the `url` to `/contacts/list/accounts`

Comment: I am using breadcrum. I can't remove that